# Split string on periods '.'

Tags: javascript, regex

I think the basic rule for the following is only split on periods not contained by brackets, but I'm having trouble translating that into the proper regex logic.

I have a string like this:

```
x['a.ab.w'].two['0'].three
```

And my best current pattern is

```
\.(?!\w*['"]\])
```

This is in javascript, and I'm trying split the sample string so that it returns as

```
x['a.ab.w']
two['0']
three
```

The regex I list above works for the case of `x['a.ab']` but fails when there are 2 or more periods in that section of the string. The output in this case is:

```
x['a
ab.w']
two['0']
```

Comment: does a period always follow a `]` if its one of the ones you want to split on?

Comment: @go-oleg Ahh good find. No, it doesn't. The string can end either as a property name, or with a bracket. Ending with a period would be considered bad syntax, but should be filtered out of this anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/\.(?![\w.]*['"\]])/
```

This seemed to work in the Regexp tester I was using.
And it also works in [my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/734QB/).

I simply changed `\w*` to `[\w.]*`

Answer (score 5):

I can see a way to do this using a mixture of `match` and `map`..

```
"x['a.ab.w'].two['0'].three"
    .match(/(?:^|\.)((?:[^'.]*|'[^']*')+(?=\.|$))/g)
        // ["x['a.ab.w']", ".two['0']", ".three"]
    .map(function (e) {
        if (e.charAt(0) === '.') return e.slice(1);
        return e;
    });
        // ["x['a.ab.w']", "two['0']", "three"]
```

Using split with this *RegExp* will give you similar results, except with extra empty entries `""` before, after and between each.

Graphic of the *RegExp*

[image: RegExp]

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'm gonna upvote it because it works and you obviously have a great understanding of regex. I'm gonna accept the other answer because its a lot simpler and I can follow along with it. Could you tell me where I could read more about how to understand the graph you shared?

Comment: Yep, the other is shorter but I wouldn't trust it personally because I can't invision how it would react in all instances. The image is linked, the website is called http://www.debuggex.com It's awesome for visualising a RegExp, but I think the easiest way to understand the graphs are by typing in some basic _RegExp_ you understand so you get a feel of how it changes. Basically it's just follow a grey line from left to right.

Comment: @PaulS. +1 For that awesome graphic. I'm going to check out that site.